# subprocess.check_output is not working with path containing "\" and spaces

Tags: python, windows, subprocess, filepath

I am trying to execute a windows executable which could be located in `"c:\program files\folder"` using python. The `get_me_the_path()` routine returns the exe path located in `"c:\program files\folder"`.
I tried various things like replacing `"\"` with `"\\"` and `" "` with `"\ "` OR even changing `"\`" to `"/"` BUT everytime I get the same error

Issue is that i want to convert `output_path` variable to some form which `subprocess.check_output` can execute without issues. Few people suggested `normpath` but that too doesn't help and I get the same error.

```
try:
    output_path= os.path.join(get_me_the_path()) ;
    exepath = output_path.replace("\\", "/").replace(" ", "\\ ")
    subprocess.check_output(exepath,shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    raise RuntimeError("command '{}' return with error (code {}): {}".format(e.cmd, e.returncode, e.output))
```

This is the error I am getting every time

```
RuntimeError: command 'C:/Program\ Files/folder/mytool.exe' return with error (code 1):
  b"'C:/Program\\' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program
    or batch file.
```

Comment: Have you tried `[exepath]`?

Comment: Try enclosing the string `get_me_the_path()` returns in double quote `"` characters so it's literally `"c:\program files\folder"`. i.e. `exepath = f'"{get_me_the_path()}"'`

Comment: @ThomasWeller : Did you mean `subprocess.check_output([exepath],shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)`

Comment: Why did you even use `shell=True`? Now you're dealing with the nastiness of manual Windows command escaping.

Comment: Yes, that way the parser knows that the first item in the list is the executable and the others are arguments (no arguments in your case, thus the array only contains the executable)

Comment: @user2357112 supports Monica : What is your suggestion. I am trying to run an exe and don't know correct way.

Comment: @ThomasWeller : with [exepath], it has stopped working altogether. Just throws exception

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica says that `shell=True` is problematic and you might want to try `shell=False` if you don't need the shell functionality.

Comment: @ThomasWeller : What should be the syntax if the exe has any arguments?

Comment: `[exepath, arg1, arg2]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Actual meaning of `shell=True` in subprocess](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3172470/actual-meaning-of-shell-true-in-subprocess)